# Making a spiral from a list of points

Tags: processing

I am trying to get spirals of ellipses to grow out of a word in Processing. I am having trouble understanding how to iterate through each point in the word (extracted using geomerative library) in order to make sure that each point is the start of each spiral. At the moment it either forms one spiral or the `translate()` function (commented out) puts the ellipses all over the place.

Here is my code:

```javascript
import geomerative.*;
//Leaf myLeaf;
float pointCount;
int freq = 1;
float phi = 1;
RFont font;
RShape grp;
RPoint[] points;
String TextTyped = "wipe";
float r = 0;
float theta = 0;
float angle;
float y; 
void setup(){
  RG.init(this);
  font = new RFont("/Users/sebastianzeki/rp_samples/samples/external_library/java_processing/geomerative/data/FreeSans.ttf",200,RFont.LEFT);
  size(800,600);
  smooth();
  background(255);
     }


    void draw(){

            stroke(0);
             strokeWeight(2);
      noFill();

        RGroup textGrouped;
        // When extracting the dots, the entered characters do not have to be processed individually.
        // The entire text textTyped can be grouped. Then the getPoints () function provides a list
        // of dots comprising the outline lines of the entire text
        textGrouped = font.toGroup (TextTyped);
        textGrouped = textGrouped.toPolygonGroup ();
        RPoint[] thePoints = textGrouped.getPoints ();


     stroke (0, 255, 255, 64);
        strokeWeight (1);

//This draws the word outline in blue circles which is fine
        for (int i = 0; i < thePoints.length; i++ ) {
          ellipse(thePoints[i].x+100, thePoints[i].y+200, 3, 3);
        }
        //This is the part that I am trying to get to draw spirals from the word points
        for (int i = 0; i < thePoints.length; i++ ) {
          translate(thePoints[i].x,thePoints[i].y);
          float x = r * cos(theta);
          float y = r * sin(theta);
          r +=0.1;
          theta += 0.01;
          ellipse(x, y, 5, 50); 
        }



}
```

Comment: In the future please try to provide a [mcve] instead of posting your whole sketch. A hardcoded set of points would have worked fine to show your problem, so there's no need to post all of that extra code. That just makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this for loop:

```javascript
 for (int i = 0; i < thePoints.length; i++ ) {
          translate(thePoints[i].x,thePoints[i].y);
          float x = r * cos(theta);
          float y = r * sin(theta);
          r +=0.1;
          theta += 0.01;
          ellipse(x, y, 5, 50); 
}
```

Here you're looping through each of the points, and then drawing a single ellipse at that point. I think what you're trying to do is draw a spiral at that point. So instead of drawing a single ellipse, you have to enter a second for loop that creates your spiral.

Something like this:

```javascript
 for (int i = 0; i < thePoints.length; i++ ) {

    //move to the point
    translate(thePoints[i].x,thePoints[i].y);

    //reset your spiral variables
    float r = 0;
    float theta = 0;

    //draw 100 points in a spiral
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          float x = r * cos(theta);
          float y = r * sin(theta);
          r += 1;
          theta += 0.1;
          ellipse(x, y, 5, 5); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ihmm. I get a blank screen. I had to remove the int in the inner loop as it had already been declared (was getting the duplicate variable error)

Comment: instead of int i I tried for (float x1 = 0; x1 < 500; x1++) which gave me the 'stack' picture but no spiralling of ellipses from the points :(

Comment: @SebastianZeki You only use the `r` and `theta` variables inside this loop, so there's no need to declare them at the top of your sketch. My example works, but it's just that: an example. You'll have to modify the code to suit your specific context.

Comment: I understand but the question revolves around how to get the spiral to derive from each point. At the moment the spirals appear but they start at what looks like a line defined by y=x rather than starting at translate(thePoints[i].x,thePoints[i].y); So although I appreciate the encouragement to 'figure it out' I'm asking this question precisely because I can't....

Comment: Look at this line: ` translate(thePoints[i].x,thePoints[i].y);` You're translating every time your draw a point, but you first have to **untranslate** from the previous point, otherwise your translations will stack up. That's why you're seeing what you're seeing. The `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions might come in handy here.

Comment: Aha. Perfect. It's working now with push matrix popMatrix